# How to set click Event to all cells in a Row ? Gridview Winforms Devexpress

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, devexpress

I have Gridview and I want to set click Event on the all cells in a Row ? How to Complete my Task ??

I tried this code but when i double click on the cell the new Form will come in Back / Behind of current Form. How to Show it on the Front ?

```
 private void gridView2_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridHitInfo celclick = gridView2.CalcHitInfo(gridControl2.PointToClient(Control.MousePosition));

        if (celclick.InRow)
        {

        }
    }
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [GridView.RowCellClick](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_RowCellClicktopic) event as follows:

```
gridControl1.DataSource = new List<Person> { 
    new Person(){ Name="John Smith"},
    new Person(){ Name="Mary Smith"}
};
gridView1.OptionsBehavior.Editable = false; // disable editing
gridView1.RowCellClick += gridView1_RowCellClick;
//...
void gridView1_RowCellClick(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.RowCellClickEventArgs e) {
    if(e.Clicks == 2) { // Double Click
        object cellValue = e.CellValue;
        //do some stuff
    }
}
//...
class Person {
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hi DmirtyG Thanks a lot thats work fine on "gridView1_RowCellClick"

Comment: HI DmirtyG, I have one more question, is it possible to fire the same event on Double Click on Cell ?

Comment: @SriHari Please take a look at my sample again. The condition `e.Clicks == 2` is checked whether or not row cell clicked via double-click...

Comment: Hi DmitryG I face one more error, this RowCellClick event work on right click, whats wrong with my code ? I tried in left click but it is not working why ?

Comment: @DmitryG How can we get clicked cell/row's table name?

Comment: I have a question, How can i know the index of the column?

Comment: You can use either the [GridColumn.VisibleIndex](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Columns.GridColumn.VisibleIndex) or the [GridColumn.AbsoluteIndex](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Columns.GridColumn.AbsoluteIndex) properties.

Answer (score 3):

I have no Visual Studio here to test it but i think it should be something like this:

```
 foreach(GridViewRow row in gridView2.Rows)
 {
       //Here you need something to get the cells out of row
       cell.Click += (s, e) => { myClickEvent(c); };
 }
```

Good luck

EDIT: Try this:

```
 foreach(GridViewRow row in gridView2.Rows)
 {
     foreach (DataControlFieldCell cell in row.Cells)
     {
         cell.Click += (s, e) => { myClickEvent(c); };
     }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for quick answering. What is Rows and RowNumber here it shows error ?

Comment: I'm not sure how to access the cells, i just found something to get the rows: foreach(GridViewRow row in GridView2.Rows)

Comment: Am new to Devexpress sorry to ask again... error shown in Rows, What is Rows here ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    private void B_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Button bt = (Button)sender;
        int productId = (int)bt.Tag;
        AddProductDataContext db = new AddProductDataContext();
        decimal Quantity;
        decimal.TryParse(txtCalculator.Text, out Quantity);
        var results = from inv in db.Inventories
                      where inv.RecId == productId
                      select new
                      {
                          inventoryName = inv.InventoryName,
                          Quantity,
                          Total = Quantity * inv.InventoryPrice
                      };





        foreach (var x in results)
        {
            DataRow newRow = dt.NewRow();
            newRow.SetField("inventoryName", x.inventoryName);
            newRow.SetField("Quantity", x.Quantity);

            newRow.SetField("Total", x.Total);
            dt.Rows.Add(newRow);



        }


        gridControl1.DataSource = dt;


    }              
    private void SaleScreen_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        dt.Columns.Add("inventoryName");
        dt.Columns.Add("Quantity");
        dt.Columns.Add("Total");

    }
```

I solved the problem in this way. Thanks to everybody for their precious helps.